# Pass parameters to url in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Is this right way to send parameter along with url in jsp page ?

```
 <a href="CancelRequest?userid=<%=idperson%>&userrnamee=<%=namee%>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the request?');">
 <input type="submit" value="CANCEL REQUEST"></input>
 </a>
```

I tried this But its not taking up the namee field .Please help

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis whats wrong in this code ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its being fetched from database somewhat like this : <%String namee=rs.getString(2);%>

Comment: @Leo Typos where is this correct u mean ?

Comment: @user3499007 Try printing the value before you pass it to the `url`

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
<input type="button" value="ADDUSER" class="button" 
onclick="location.href='UserController?action=insert'"/></p>

<input type="button" value="BACK" class="button" 
onclick="location.href='employeeCategory.jsp'" />
```